# Gems not getting loaded on cPanel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, cpanel

I've an application which is hosted on a shared hosting.
Application runs fine on local machine but when I deployed it, it throws error.

```
NoMethodError in Polls#new

Showing /home/applogic/public_html/Impression_Logic/app/views/polls/_form.html.erb where line #24 raised:

undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class
Extracted source (around line #24):

21:         </div>
22: 
23:     
24:         <%=form_for @poll, :html => {:multipart => true, :class => "form-horizontal", :id => "new_poll"}  do |f|%>
25: 
26:             <legend>Create a New Image Test</legend>
27:
```

I added two gems Bitly and Gibbon (for mailchimp). I did bundle install on local machine but in cPanel they have an application which goes through the Gemfile and loads all.

They are loaded in a specific directory on my shared hosting.
If I comment out the code that uses Gem classes, application works fine on Server also.

I tried copying gem folders from my local application (vendors/ruby/1.9.1/gems/) to the server but no luck.

It must be something silly but I'm very new to Rails.
I did search on Google but it didn't help.

It looks like Gem issue but error thrown is where application stopped.

Here's the stacktrace http://pastie.org/5364251

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps accept some answer first also the error is not a gem error it state some thing wrong in you code check you controller is `@poll` is actually defined there

Comment: Application runs fine on my Local Machine. If something is wrong in Code, it should fail on Local machine too. No?

Comment: what is `@poll` I believe it is `nil` do so us the code where `@poll` is set